# Fetching Worklet name during run time in Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I would like to get the worklet name during Run Time in the post session success command task inside the worklet. If I am using $PMWorkflowName, then I am getting the workflow name of the worklet not the worklet name.

Can you please help me in this.

Comment: May not be possible. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi Koushik, I just wanted to pass the input parameters for a shell script to run the pmcmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that, informatica does not have the build-in variables for worklet, so we have to create a worklet variable with default value as worklet name.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there is not built-in variable for worklet name. For future reference: here's [a list of built-in variables](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-language-reference/variables/built-in-variables.html).